# assign new key names to array from old array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to convert currency data to a new array to use for my currency conversion. But I need a different kind of array.
I want to create an array that looks like this:

The array from the json file looks like:

```
{
   "eur":{
      "code":"EUR",
      "alphaCode":"EUR",
      "numericCode":"978",
      "name":"Euro",
      "rate":0.83563518721183,
      "date":"Mon, 7 May 2018 00:00:01 GMT"
   },
   "gbp":{
      "code":"GBP",
      "alphaCode":"GBP",
      "numericCode":"826",
      "name":"U.K. Pound Sterling",
      "rate":0.73757713865121,
      "date":"Mon, 7 May 2018 00:00:01 GMT"
   },
etc...
 }
```

I want to make it look like:

```
   {
    rates: {
        AED: 3.672538,
        AFN: 66.809999,
        ALL: 125.716501,
        AMD: 484.902502,
        ANG: 1.788575,
        AOA: 135.295998,
        ARS: 9.750101,
        AUD: 1.390866,
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The code I used:

```
$.getJSON(
      'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json',
      function (data) {
        var newRates = [];
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(
          function (val, idx, array) {
            var newObj = Object.assign(
              { val },
              { '': data[val].rate });
            newRates.push(newObj);
          }
        );
        console.log(newRates);
    )
```

Comment: "I want to create an array that looks like this" — That is not an array!

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: From your code and your result, I'd say `data` is **already** in the form you said you want.

Comment: @baao fixed edit

Comment: An array has ordered elements indexed from 0 to n and are denoted with [ and ] in JSON. What you have are objects, which are unordered collections of named data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an object by mapping single object and assign it to a singel object.

```js
$.getJSON(
    'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json',
    function(data) {
        var result = Object.assign(
                ...Object
                    .entries(data)
                    .map(([key, { rate }]) => ({ [key.toUpperCase()]: rate }))
            );

        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I mean! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you could obtain what you want by simply directly assigning it, try this:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json',
    function (data) {
        var newRates = {'rates': []}; // <--
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(
            function (val, idx, array) {
                newRates['rates'][val] = data[val].rate;
            }
        );
        console.log(newRates);
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, this also works fine! Now I have multiple solutions :)
Nina uses a more modern way. What is the most efficient one to use in the end?

Comment: Unless you have a reaaaaaally huge JSON, it doesn't really make a difference, it's just a few microseconds. But if you wan't to test it, you can use console.time() -> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#time

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an array that looks like this

As Quentin said, that's not an array, it's a non-array object. (Arrays are also objects, hence the "non-array" bit.)

From the result you're getting in your code, it's clear that `data` is **already** in the format you said you wanted for `rates`; just use it directly:

```
var obj = {rates: data};
```

Here's the proof:

```js
console.log("Be sure to scroll down");

var data = {
  AED: 3.672538,
  AFN: 66.809999,
  ALL: 125.716501,
  AMD: 484.902502,
  ANG: 1.788575,
  AOA: 135.295998,
  ARS: 9.750101,
  AUD: 1.390866,
  /* ... */
};

// Applying your code to it:
var newRates = [];
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(
  function (val, idx, array) {
    var newObj = Object.assign(
      { val },
      { '': data[val].rate });
    newRates.push(newObj);
  }
);
console.log(newRates);

// But instead, just use it directly
var newRates2 = {rates: data};
console.log(newRates2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```